# iOS .plist download time-out parameter?

Tags: ios, download, timeout, plist

Is there an iOS .plist parameter that can be set to specify/increase the app download timeout? We have low bandwidth enterprise customers and they are getting time-outs when trying to download iOS apps.

Comment: out of curiosity, what is the size of your app?

Comment: The app that times out is 177.3mb

Comment: I also wonder the answer, but If i were you I would try to shrink the size of the app as much as possible,I would download all necessary data over web after user installs the app, because even in normal conditions Apple does not accept app larger than 50mb, you are distributing it yourself and your app size is hugee.